# Estimate the center of a symmetric distribution using sample mean, median, midrange, and Mid-quartile

Tags: r

I need to use N(0,1) in Rstudio to estimate the center of a distribution using the sample mean, median, midrange, and midquartile, for n = 10, 30 and 100.

I have written the simulation which runs without an error message, but when trying to change from n = 10 to n = 30, I get an error about the quantile function, which I think is where my issue lies.

```
#N(0,1)
 variab.dist.n = function(m = 1000, n = 10) {
  average = c(); med = c(); midrange = c(); midquartile = c();
  for(i in 1:m) {
    x = rnorm(n)
average[i] = mean(x)
med[i] = median(x)
midrange[i] = ((min(x) + max(x)) / 2)
midquartile[i] = (quantile(variab.dist.n, 0.25) + quantile(variab.dist.n, 0.75))/2
    }
  data.frame(average, med, midrange, midquartile)
  }

variab.dist.n.30 = variab.dist.n(n = 30) 
attach(variab.dist.n.30)
boxplot(average, med, midrange, midquartile, 
names = c("Mean", "Median", "Midrange", "Midquartile"), 
ylab = "Estimate", 
main = "Sampling Distributions for N(0,1)")
detach(variab.dist.200)
```

I expect the center to be more precise using n =  30 and n = 100 than n = 10.

Comment: midquartile[i] = (quantile(x, 0.25) + quantile(x, 0.75))/2 ?